# Undefined variable: professors

Tags: laravel

In the show function in my controller I passed the variable `$professors`
In the controller method I am passing the `variable` like this -

```
public function show(Professor $professor)
{
    $professors = Professor::all();
    return view('professor.show',compact('professors'));   
}
```

I am trying to display the professor `name` in the `show.blade.php` like this

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="row">
        <strong class="col-sm-2">Name:</strong>
            {{$professors->name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting this error-

> Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

Where am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution

```
 public function show(Professor $professor)
{
    $professors = Professor::find($professor->id);
    return view('professor.show',compact('professors'));   
}
```

I forgot the `find($professor->id);` works for me now guys